# Unwanted space at the extreme bottom of the home page of wordpress website

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, web

I am having a problem with the website i've created. Its having unwanted space at the extreme bottom of the home page. No matter what i did, it still remains there. The website is built in wordpress.
I tried removing the closing **php** tag from the bottom of **functions.php**.
 Nothing's really worked.

The page link is  **http://icoachgym.com/**

Comment: There is no unwanted space there. This looks like spam. Consider [following website rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you think this is a mistake.

Comment: Hi. It was there. I got the perfect answer just after 2 minutes of posting this question. So it got fixed. Thanks for reviewing..         It was due to the following code in my css file.       ** .call-to-action {  margin-bottom: 500px;} **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.call-to-action class has a margin-bottom of 500px. In the file my-custom-styles.css.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with your css. It is on line 286. http://icoachgym.com/wp-content/themes/icoachgym/assets/css/my-custom-styles.css

my-custom-styles.css:286

```
.call-to-action {
    margin-bottom: 500px;
}
```

you need to change that to this:

```
.call-to-action {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```